# sparql how to output resources as prefix:keyword rather than full uri

Tags: rdf, sparql

I am wanting to list a lot of returned data from a sparql query into a table, and in order to shorten the display of it, I would like to display it the same way that dbpedia shows it on their website:

```
dbo:assets             1.1753E11

dbo:division           dbr:Computer_hardware
                       dbr:Software

dbo:equity             1.1868E10

dbo:foundationPlace    dbr:New_York
                       dbr:Endicott,_New_York
```

see screenshot below to see the actual user experience:

[image]

is there a way to output the resources with their prefixes like this using SPARQL? if so, how is it done?

Comment: As Jeen noted in an answer, there's nothing really built in to do this.  There are some ways of doing this within a SPARQL query (but you have to have the prefixes declared within the query) in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in SPARQL itself that allows you to do that. Some SPARQL engines may offer a (custom) result syntax format that does this for you, but in general, you will need to post-process the result and manually convert from full URI to prefixed name. How, exactly, you do that depends on what platform/programming language you are working in.